# How to read ID3 Tag in an MP3 using Python?

Tags: python, tags, mp3, id3

Does anyone has an experience of reading and writing ID3 tags in an MP3 file or a WMA file? There are some libraries but I would like to do it from the scratch. :-)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp3%20python

Comment: This is my attempt at deciphering the meta... https://github.com/JayRizzo/MP3Player/blob/master/mp3TagEditor.py

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dive into Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905200140/http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html) uses MP3 ID3 tags as an example.

Comment: Damn, as soon as I read this question I was going to suggest that.

Comment: A bit outdated now, though...

Answer (score 13):

Mutagen https://bitbucket.org/lazka/mutagen
*Edited 14/09/23 with current code host location*

eyeD3 http://eyed3.nicfit.net/

Comment: Top (Mutagen) link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Try [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/), it's a program and a module.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google showed up http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/

Maybe this works for you ?

Comment: You should read the question. He specifically said he would like to do it from scratch.