# Reading ID3 Tags in Python 3

Tags: audio, python-3.x, metadata, id3

I'm stuck. I'm trying to find a way to read ID3 tags in an MP3 & FLAC files in Python 3. Everywhere I turn, the answer is about some library or module that only works in Python 2, including [questions I've found on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736813/how-to-read-id3-tag-in-an-mp3-using-python) here at StackOverflow. Does anyone know of a module that works with Python 3?

Comment: There's some effort in progress to [port mutagen to Python 3](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/issues/detail?id=27). This [branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~berdario/mutagen/mutagen-py3) seems to be mostly functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this project called [stagger](https://code.google.com/p/stagger/) !

Comment: Hi, I've tried using this and it seems to fail if you try to read tags on a file without id3 tags! Is there a way to check for that first? I can't find much documentation on Stagger at all!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I wrote my own library, supports MP3 and OGG files, take a look to the documentation:

http://pytag.rtfd.org

Comment: I like it, but I also need to get the data out of my FLAC files too. I have a lot of them. I'm lookin' to make a database of my music collection & update it regularly by having it spider my mp3 & FLAC files.

Comment: I'm trying to use your library, but I'm getting the error "ImportError: Unable to find magic library". I'm new to Python, so any idea why this is?

Comment: @AdiBradfield Did you install pytag using 'pip install pytag'? What OS do you have?

Comment: Yes I used pip. I'm on Windows 8 x86

Comment: @AdiBradfield In that case the problem is windows, as far as I know, there isn't a magic library for windows. Anyway, I wanted to make the use of libmagic optional, in that case should work for windows. I would try to make a new release this weekend to solve the problem.

Comment: @JoséLuis Ahh that would be great! But there's no rush for me, I downgraded to Python 2.7 and used the Mutagen package, and with ALOT of fiddling about, I finally managed to extract the data I needed! I would have been more patient, but I needed it to create a song list for a Karaoke night tomorrow night! I will work on an opensource version of the code that I've got running at the moment, since I only found paid programs that will make a karaoke song list, believe it or not, and all the free ones had ridiculously low limits on!