# Accessing mp3 file information

Tags: python, linux, bash, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing mp3 Meta-Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python)

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 (Linux) and would like to access/read/edit information located in the "Notes" tab of mp3 files.  How can I go about doing this?  Here's a screenshot to a test.mp3 file and the "Notes" tab I'm trying to access/read/edit the file properties.

I tried using the application id3tool to read the info from test.mp3 but
it comes back with

```
Filename: test.mp3
No ID3 Tag
```

[image]

Comment: An mp3 file does not have tabs anymore than an mp3 file has windows or buttons. An mp3 file has metadata, which the GNOME application you are using to read it is accessing and displaying in a tab.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be mp3 Meta-Data.  I tried using id3tool test.mp3 and it comes back with Filename: test.mp3 and No ID3 Tag.  I added the extra info to the question

Answer (score 0):

The value being displayed in this tab is most likely the `comment` field in the `id3` or `id3v2`-format tags. Find a python library to access mp3 metadata, or find an application which reads mp3 metadata and use:

```
import subprocess as proc

command = ['/usr/bin/appname', '/path/to/myfile.mp3']
output = proc.Popen(command, stdout=proc.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()
```

to read the output.