# Any Python modules (for Windows and Unix-like) to extract info from video/audio files?

Tags: python

Wondering which Python module to use to extract meta info (including container format, codec format, resolution, frame rate, length) from video/audio files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would make for an interesting module. Here's an SO question for MP3's: [Accessing mp3 Meta-Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python)

Sourceforge python package that does some images and audio formats: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mmpython/

Not sure if it covers all the formats you're looking for.

Comment: I might switch to use mediainfo cause kaa-metadata cannot handle .mp4 well.

Comment: [Which one](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download) are you using? Is it possible to use `libmediainfo0` and `libzen0` directly?

Comment: mediainfo works really well, but your reply was mmpython, which can't extract fps from .mp4. I switched to use http://code.google.com/p/ffvideo/ cause it works really well by ffmpeg .

Comment: yes, I meant mediainfo in my comment, since there were several packages for linux. not sure how a lib would be used directly in python. +1 for ffvideo.

Comment: I think the only issue currently is that ffvideo (or more precisely, ffmpeg family) is really hard to make a compile under Windows. lol~