# turn a folder of mp3's into a searchable component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a folder which houses probably 1000 mp3s. I want to parse the mp3 information to automatically get the track title, artist, and src location to store in a json file. Is there a way to map over the folder of mp3s and create this. I have tried to figure something out but still cant event begin to solve this problem. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing mp3 Meta-Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-meta-data-with-python)

Comment: please try to add more information regarding your needs. eg: what do you mean by searchable component? is it react component?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a directory with the utility [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

```
fs.readdir(dataFolder, (err, files) => { // Something fancy });
```

and you can check the metadata of the mp3 files based the id3 with a tool like [Music Metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata)