# How can I get banner art, artist name and the song name from a .mp3 file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, albumart

**

> I want to make a music app and I am successful in getting the songs and playing them using SoundLoader from kivy.core.audio 
>  I also added them in a OneLineIconList item BUT I can't figure out how to get the album art/banner art, artist name, song name and the duration of the song using only python
> And also is it possible to get it all offline. If yes, so can you please give me the code for that
> THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

**

Comment: Accessing MP3 metadata with Python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-metadata-with-python

Comment: @Xyanight That's alright but is there any way to get the banner art of the song?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

st = os.stat("file.dat")
```

This function takes the name of a file, and returns a 10-member tuple with the following contents:

```
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)
```

Here's a short example of the usage:

```
import os, time
from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc

try:
    st = os.stat(file)
except IOError:
    print "failed to get information about", file
else:
    print "file size:", st[ST_SIZE]
    print "file modified:", time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME]))
```

Source: http://effbot.org/zone/python-fileinfo.htm