# Mutagen adding year metatag to an MP3 file?

Tags: python, audio, meta-tags, mutagen

I'm using EasyMP3 from [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.org/) to add metadata tags to an audio file. But in EasyMP3 the year tag is not defined so I am getting an error saying year is not a valid key.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```py
from mutagen.mp3 import EasyMP3

tags = EasyMP3('test.mp3')
tags['title'] = 'Some title'
tags['artist'] = 'Some artist'
tags['year'] = '2022'
tags.save()
```

This is the error:

```
mutagen.easyid3.EasyID3KeyError: "'year' is not a valid key"
```

Since I just started using mutagen I don't know much about its other instances. How can I add the year metadata tag to the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing MP3 metadata with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-metadata-with-python)

Answer (score 3):

Folllowing the documentation of [EasyMP3](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp3.html?highlight=easymp3#mutagen.mp3.EasyMP3) it returns a [EasyID3](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html#mutagen.easyid3.EasyID3). Not all tags are supported out of the box but you can register others you might need using [RegisterKey](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html#mutagen.easyid3.EasyID3.RegisterKey) (and more related functions).

For `year` it should be possible to use `EasyID3.RegisterTextKey("year", "TDRC")` - check [id3v2.4.0](https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames).

For your example, the following code would work:

```py
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.mp3 import EasyMP3

EasyID3.RegisterTextKey('year', 'TDRC')

tags = EasyMP3('test.mp3')
tags['title'] = 'Some title'
tags['artist'] = 'Some artist'
tags['year'] = '2022'
tags.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

for EasyID3 the tag is 'date' or 'originaldate'