# How to access/modify [Comments, Group Description, Mood] Properties from a MP3 file via Python

Tags: python, mp3

i am trying to modify this properties from an mp3 file using python,
and also not sure its mp3 file properties or windows file properties.
i tried all below lib

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mp3_tagger import MP3File
import eyed3
```

[image]

but None of them have the access to these properties
could someoe please help me how to remove these properties?

thanks,

Bala.

Comment: Did this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-metadata-with-python

Comment: nope i checked that post and i could not find a way to access these properites

Comment: found a shortcut.. windows allows to edit these properities from multiple selection.